# Is it Possible to Alias Config Variables on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I'm currently writing a tutorial on setting up Wordpress on Heroku. Right now I'm using the `ClearDB` add-on which sets a `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL` ENV variable automatically. Is it possible to alias the `ENV` variable through Heroku as `DATABASE_URL`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm not sure this information will be helpful for anyone but just in case:

This question involves an eroneous assertion.  The ClearDB add-on does not set a CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL ENV variable.  The ClearDB add-on creates a CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL config var.  When the app is started an ENV variable is created from the config var.  These two variables are different and could even have different values if you changed the ENV variable in your code base.

Of course, within your code base, you can do whatever you want with the ENV variables.

As to whether config vars can reference other config vars, or other ENV variables, or vica versa - I don't know.  But surely this would be something pretty hacky, and contrary to intended use, and proper coding practice, and socially responsible behavior.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but that sounds like a distinction without a difference; your code still has to reference `ENV[CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL]`. If you want to use your own name (say, DB_URL) to prevent vendor-lockin, the environment variable approach makes that very difficult. Am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: I don't see the difficulty.  You could create an initializer with the following:  ```ENV['DATABASE_URL'] = ENV['CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL']```.  Now you can reference ```ENV['DATABASE_URL']``` in your app.  The OP, however, asked how to do the equivalent "through Heroku".  There seemed to be some misconceptions which were obscuring the issues which I tried to disambiguate.

Comment: Right, but that still means that you're including what are essentially environment details in your code (the particular DB plugin) that might not apply if, say, you were to deploy it to somewhere other than Heroku. Not the end of the world, of course, but it does kind of tie your code to Heroku.

Comment: I see what you mean now.  And I agree.  I wasn't really offering a solution to this issue in my answer, rather, I was attempting to clarify the issue and the terms involved, in case that would help by removing some confusion.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question asked. This is not an answer at all.

Answer (score 8):

It's not possible to alias an config var or refer to one from another. I asked a similar question and this is what they said:

> I'm afraid that Config Variables can't refer to each other in this
> way, as they are simple a collection of Names and Values, with no
> interpolation or calculation available to the values.
>
> You might like try a
> [profile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#the-profile-file)
> file...

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue - where I'm trying to use an app in a pipeline connected to 2 different heroku DB's - in order to keep all he environments consistent in code, I did the following:

Heroku Configs:

```
DATABASE_URL=XXXXXXXX  - this was the first DB that heroku attached
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_JADE_URL=XXXX - this was the second DB that heroku attached (the key name changes in each environment)
SECOND_DB_KEY_NAME=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_JADE_URL
```

(ie. after each environment was set up - I added a reference to the new key)

This second DB key name, does not change if the DB credentials refresh.

In code, I then did the following at start up:

```
const databaseUrlKey = process.env.SECOND_DB_KEY_NAME
process.env['SECOND_DATABASE_URL'] = process.env[databaseUrlKey]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'll just say something stupid, but why not just do this:

`heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL`

In code: 
`ENV[ENV['DATABASE_URL']]`

Comment: because that sets DATABASE_URL to the string "CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL"

Comment: @jpw Exactly! So we will have ENV['CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL'] which contain right DB url. I'm using this hack on heroku, and it is working, if you interested.

Comment: It works *today* perhaps, but, if heroku re-points DATABASE_URL to a different value - which they reserve the right to do -  it will overwrite the ENV var, so you'll end up with ENV [ 'postgres:somenewnewurl' ] which will of course be nil. see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql which says specifically:  "The value of your app’s DATABASE_URL config var might change at any time. You should not rely on this value either inside or outside your Heroku app."

Comment: no, because Heroku will change value but not env variable name. That’s why we are  pointing to name but not to value.